# Which clearfix method?

Tags: html, css, css-float

/* Clear Fix */

```
.clearfix:after {content: ".";display:block;height:0;clear:both;visibility:hidden;}
* html .clearfix {height:1%;}
```

or

```
.clearfix:after {content: ".";display:block;height:0;clear:both;visibility:hidden;}
* html .clearfix, *:first-child+html .clearfix {zoom:1;}
```

Which would work the best?
I used first one by now and never had an issue..
Thanks.

Comment: i think you made a mistake on the second one > in my experience you have to put IE6 and IE7 hack on separate line statement or it won't work

Comment: could anyone confirm this one?

Comment: why waste properties on hiding the dot you've added, when `content:""` creates element without creating a visible character and line!?

Answer (score 3):

Most succinct technique is setting overflow:hidden for modern browsers:

```
overflow:hidden;
zoom:1;
```

If an element needs to flow out of the dimensions ( negative margins or positioning ) then clearfix:

```
#el:after { content:""; clear:both; display:block; visibility:hidden; }
```

For IE6 and below, you need to trigger hasLayout ( through a width, zoom:1, height, and other property/value combos ). Starting with IE7, overflow will clear the floats.

Answer (score 1):

The latter seems to be fine because it also considers IE6 (`zoom:1;`).

Comment: either of those account for IE6. the latter is just more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

This has always worked for me. Very similar to yours

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: "."; 
    display: block;
    height: 0; 
    font-size:0;
    clear: both; 
    visibility:hidden;
}
    .clearfix{display: inline-block;}
    * html .clearfix {height: 1%;}
    .clearfix {display:block;}
```

Comment: inline-block and block along with height:1% is redundant. `content:""` is good enough.